# Hyperlinks pasted in MS Word 2010 inactive

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Why would a link pasted into MS Word 2010 appear as plain text after you hit the carriage return and go to the next line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto-hyperlink feature can be disabled in Word, perhaps yours is.

To change the hyperlink feature permanently:

1. View the options. (*File* tab, select *Options*).
2. In the left column, select *Proofing*.
3. Click the *AutoCorrect Options...* button.
4. Select the *AutoFormat* tab.
5. Clear or select the *Internet and network paths with hyperlinks* check box.
6. Select the *AutoFormat As You Type* tab.
7. Clear or select the *Internet and network paths with hyperlinks* check box.
8. Click *OK*.
9. Click *OK*.

Comment: The Word file in question is stored on a network drive.  The answer works locally, but not where it's stored on the network.  Are network folder permissions known to affect file characteristics?  It's a Windows network.

Comment: Weird, that setting affects Word in general, and shouldn't have anything to do with what document you're opening, or where you're opening it from. If you copy the same file locally, then it works as expected?